# C# Generic Class EF6, Save Instance (this)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to create a Generic class for my Entity Framework models.

```
using UM4RS.persistance;
using UM4RS.Persistance;

public abstract class MyEntity<TObject>  where TObject : class, IBaseEntity
{
    static readonly ModelContext ModelContext = new ModelContext();

    // class method to save object
    public static TObject Save(TObject t)
    {
        if (t == null) return null;       
        ModelContext.Set<TObject>().Add(t);
        ModelContext.SaveChanges();
        return t;
    }

    // instance method to save the current instance
    public void Save()
    {
         Save(this); //<- ERROR: Cannot convert MyEnttity<TObject> to TObject

        // Also tried
        ModelContext.Set<TObject>().Add(this); //<- Same error here
        ModelContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My model classes inherits from MyEntity

```
public class User : MyEntity<User>, IBaseEntity
{
    ...
}
```

Finally, what I want to archive is:

```
User usr = new User();
usr.Save(); // <- Call the instance method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `User` class is a `IBaseEntity` which is in turn `TObject` , you can cast it

```
var baseEntity = this as TObject;
Debug.Assert(baseEntity!=null);//assert that its not violated
Save(baseEntity); 
ModelContext.Set<TObject>().Add(baseEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but the cast was to TObject no to IBaseEntity. 
var baseEntity = this as TObject;